# Объявите класс A с двумя целыми числами и двумя методами

Tags: java

Объявите класс A с двумя целыми числами и двумя методами

Метод первый присваивает значения переменным с клавиатуры
Метод второй складывает переменные
Я меня не получается правильно передать аргумент в функцию, создается локальная переменная, но нужно присваивать ведь к глобальной

```
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int a = 0;
        check(a);

        System.out.println(a);

    }

    private static void check(int a) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = scanner.nextInt();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, укажите, что в нем не работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/klkvj.png

Comment: Исправил и добавил код.

Comment: функции здесь нет. есть только методы. если вас интересует функция, то решение примерно такое BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> SUM = (a, b) -> a + b; Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); Integer result = SUM.apply(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A {
    int a;
    int b;

    void method1() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = sc.nextInt();
        b = sc.nextInt();
    }

    int method2() {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```